# Hide important Strings in LibGdx Game -module core-

Tags: java, string, libgdx, obfuscation

I need to hide some important Strings in the module `core` from My LibGdx Game

```
public class MyStrings {


public static String Key1 = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
public static String Key2 = "XXXXXXXXXX";
public static String Key3 = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
....
}
```

I tried to use the `Gradle` method, but i can't use `BuildConfig`. i can't use also `Base64.decode...`... `ProGuard` didn't help, and i think i can't use C/C++ way either.

Please Help.

Comment: Usually my first reaction when reading questions like these is "Why do you need to do this?" - What exactly do these strings represent that they need to be secret and in the binaries you ship to your client?

Comment: i just need to make things harder for reverse ingeniers

Comment: Simple obfuscation enough? See here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384444/simple-algorithm-for-mixing-obfuscating-a-string-with-pre-defined-chars ?

Answer (score 2):

The obfuscation feature that you are looking for is [String Encryption](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dasho/features#string), which as you noted [is not supported by ProGuard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10220069/does-proguard-work-to-obfuscate-static-string-constants/12665420#12665420).  Other obfuscators, such as [DashO](https://www.preemptive.com/products/dasho/overview), [KlassMaster](https://www.zelix.com/klassmaster/index.html?id=010), and [DexGuard](https://www.guardsquare.com/en/dexguard) (for Android only) do support this feature.

Alternatively, as @RobAu suggested, you can [write your own solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384444/simple-algorithm-for-mixing-obfuscating-a-string-with-pre-defined-chars).

Full disclosure:  I work at PreEmptive solutions, the company that produces DashO.